# jquery ajax error - unable to capture the error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I am trying to get the login status thro ajax, But the ajax query is not happening properly.

```
function getdetails(playlistname) {
alert(playlistname);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "model/login_details1.php",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        alert("before send");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("ajax error - arun");
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    },
    data: {
        fname: name,
        playlistname: playlistname
    }
}).done(function (result) {

    if (!sessionStorage['pid']) {
        sessionStorage['pid'] = result;

    } //    window.location = "Playlist.html";
});
}
```

I am getting the alert before posting but the alert after post ( error ) is vanishing.

Comment: Why not put everything as a .done, .fail, .always and see what happens?

Comment: first i started with done. its not giving any meaningful reply. In one other post i saw its related to same origin policy. Can some one tell this is also something how to handle same origin policy. In my case its same domain

Comment: Just covering the obvious, but is your request even causing an error to begin with? What is e.g. Firebug telling you? In addition to what @TimSPQR has said, you could also assign `complete:` and `success:` event handlers with some `alert()` or `console.log()` code. Side note: Formatted code helps us to give quick and relevant feedback. ;]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following format of ajax that may help you to find out the error very quickly.

```
function getdetails(playlistname) {
    alert(playlistname);
    var name = "" //here is your value.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "model/login_details1.php",
        data: {
            fname: name,
            playlistname: playlistname
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            alert("before send");
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result); //use this to see the response from serverside
            if (!sessionStorage['pid']) {
                sessionStorage['pid'] = result;
            }
            //  window.location = "Playlist.html";
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("ajax error - arun");
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```